# Cannot read property 'id' of null error when click delete button in dynamic rows

Tags: magento2.3, dynamic-rows

error when I click on delete button in dynamic rows.

etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="custom-tab-with-content" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomTab</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
</config>
```

Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomTab

```
<?php

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Framework\Phrase;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Container;
use Magento\Ui\Component\DynamicRows;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\ActionDelete;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;

class CustomTab extends AbstractModifier
{
    const FIELDSET_DYNAMIC_ROWS_NAME = 'dynamic_rows';
    const FIELD_IS_DELETE = 'actionDelete';
    const FIELD_NAME_SELECT = 'select_field';

    protected $_backendUrl;
    protected $_productLoader;
    protected $_modelCustomtabFactory;
    protected $_ingredientOptions;

    /**
     * @var LocatorInterface
     */
    protected $locator;

    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $meta = [];

    /**
     * @param LocatorInterface $locator
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param CustomTabFactory $modelFriendFactory
     * @param ProductFactory $_productLoader
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl
     * @param IngredientOptions $ingredientOptions
     */
    public function __construct(
        LocatorInterface $locator,
        ArrayManager $arrayManager,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        CustomTabFactory $modelFriendFactory,
        ProductFactory $_productLoader,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\UrlInterface $backendUrl,
        IngredientOptions $ingredientOptions
    ) {
        $this->locator = $locator;
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        $this->_modelCustomtabFactory = $modelFriendFactory;
        $this->_productLoader = $_productLoader;
        $this->_backendUrl = $backendUrl;
        $this->_ingredientOptions = $ingredientOptions;
    }

    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        return $data;
    }

    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $this->meta = $meta;
        $this->addCustomTab();

        return $this->meta;
    }

    protected function addCustomTab()
    {
        $this->meta = array_merge_recursive(
            $this->meta,
            [
                static::FIELDSET_DYNAMIC_ROWS_NAME => $this->getTabConfig(),
            ]
        );
    }

    protected function getTabConfig()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Ingredients'),
                        'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => '',
                        'provider' => static::FORM_NAME . '.product_form_data_source',
                        'ns' => static::FORM_NAME,
                        'collapsible' => true,
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'children' => [
                'customTab' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'componentType' => DynamicRows::NAME,
                                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid',
                                // 'template' => 'Magento_Backend/dynamic-rows/grid',
                                'defaultRecord' => true,
                                'addButton' > true,
                                'links' => [
                                    'insertData' => '${ $.provider }:${ $.dataProvider }'
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        'record' => [
                            'arguments' => [
                                'data' => [
                                    'config' => [
                                        'componentType' => Container::NAME,
                                        'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record',
                                        'isTemplate' => true,
                                        'is_collection' => true,
                                    ],
                                ],
                            ],
                            'children' => [
                                static::FIELD_NAME_SELECT => $this->getSelectFieldConfig(1),                          
                                static::FIELD_IS_DELETE => $this->getIsDeleteFieldConfig(4)

                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]

        ];
    }

    protected function getSelectFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Ingredients'),
                        'componentType' => Select::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => static::FIELD_NAME_SELECT,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                        'options' => $this->_ingredientOptions->getAllOptions(),
                        'visible' => true,
                        'disabled' => false,
                        'validation' => [
                            'required-entry' => true,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }

    protected function getIsDeleteFieldConfig($sortOrder)
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'componentType' => ActionDelete::NAME,
                        'fit' => true,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

dynamic-row-grid.js

```
    /**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    './dynamic-rows'
], function (_, dynamicRows) {
    'use strict';

    return dynamicRows.extend({
        defaults: {
            dataProvider: '',
            insertData: [],
            map: null,
            cacheGridData: [],
            deleteProperty: false,
            positionProvider: 'position',
            dataLength: 0,
            identificationProperty: 'id',
            identificationDRProperty: 'id',
            listens: {
                'insertData': 'processingInsertData',
                'recordData': 'initElements setToInsertData'
            },
            mappingSettings: {
                enabled: true,
                distinct: true
            }
        },

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this.setToInsertData = _.debounce(this.setToInsertData, 200);

            return this._super();
        },

        /**
         * Calls 'initObservable' of parent
         *
         * @returns {Object} Chainable.
         */
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super()
                .observe([
                    'insertData'
                ]);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Set data from recordData to insertData
         */
        setToInsertData: function () {
            var insertData = [],
                obj;

            if (this.recordData().length && !this.update) {
                _.each(this.recordData(), function (recordData) {
                    obj = {};
                    obj[this.map[this.identificationProperty]] = recordData[this.identificationProperty];
                    insertData.push(obj);
                }, this);

                if (insertData.length) {
                    this.source.set(this.dataProvider, insertData);
                }
            }
        },

        /**
         * Initialize children
         *
         * @returns {Object} Chainable.
         */
        initChildren: function () {
            this.getChildItems().forEach(function (data, index) {
                this.processingAddChild(data, this.startIndex + index, data[this.identificationDRProperty]);
            }, this);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Initialize elements from grid
         *
         * @param {Array} data
         *
         * @returns {Object} Chainable.
         */
        initElements: function (data) {
            var newData = this.getNewData(data);

            this.parsePagesData(data);

            if (newData.length) {
                if (this.insertData().length) {
                    this.processingAddChild(newData[0], data.length - 1, newData[0][this.identificationProperty]);
                }
            }

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * Delete record instance
         * update data provider dataScope
         *
         * @param {String|Number} index - record index
         * @param {String|Number} recordId
         */
        deleteRecord: function (index, recordId) {
            this.updateInsertData(recordId);
            this._super();
        },

        /**
         * Updates insertData when record is deleted
         *
         * @param {String|Number} recordId
         */
        updateInsertData: function (recordId) {
            var data = this.getElementData(this.insertData(), recordId),
            prop = this.map[this.identificationDRProperty];

            this.insertData(_.reject(this.source.get(this.dataProvider), function (recordData) {
                return recordData[prop].toString() === data[prop].toString();
            }, this));
        },

        /**
         * Find data object by index
         *
         * @param {Array} array - data collection
         * @param {Number} index - element index
         * @param {String} property - to find by property
         *
         * @returns {Object} data object
         */
        getElementData: function (array, index, property) {
            var obj = {},
                result;

            property ? obj[property] = index : obj[this.map[this.identificationDRProperty]] = index;
            result = _.findWhere(array, obj);

            if (!result) {
                property ?
                    obj[property] = index.toString() :
                    obj[this.map[this.identificationDRProperty]] = index.toString();
            }

            result = _.findWhere(array, obj);

            return result;
        },

        /**
         * Processing pages before addChild
         *
         * @param {Object} ctx - element context
         * @param {Number|String} index - element index
         * @param {Number|String} prop - additional property to element
         */
        processingAddChild: function (ctx, index, prop) {
            if (this._elems.length > this.pageSize) {
                return false;
            }

            this.showSpinner(true);
            this.addChild(ctx, index, prop);
        },

        /**
         * Contains old data with new
         *
         * @param {Array} data
         *
         * @returns {Array} changed data
         */
        getNewData: function (data) {
            var changes = [],
                tmpObj = {};

            if (data.length !== this.relatedData.length) {
                _.each(data, function (obj) {
                    tmpObj[this.identificationDRProperty] = obj[this.identificationDRProperty];

                    if (!_.findWhere(this.relatedData, tmpObj)) {
                        changes.push(obj);
                    }
                }, this);
            }

            return changes;
        },

        /**
         * Processing insert data
         *
         * @param {Object} data
         */
        processingInsertData: function (data) {
            var changes,
                obj = {};

            changes = this._checkGridData(data);
            this.cacheGridData = data;

            if (changes.length) {
                obj[this.identificationDRProperty] = changes[0][this.map[this.identificationProperty]];

                if (_.findWhere(this.recordData(), obj)) {
                    return false;
                }

                changes.forEach(function (changedObject) {
                    this.mappingValue(changedObject);
                }, this);
            }
        },

        /**
         * Mapping value from grid
         *
         * @param {Array} data
         */
        mappingValue: function (data) {
            var obj = {},
                tmpObj = {};

            if (this.mappingSettings.enabled) {
                _.each(this.map, function (prop, index) {
                    obj[index] = !_.isUndefined(data[prop]) ? data[prop] : '';
                }, this);
            } else {
                obj = data;
            }

            if (this.mappingSettings.distinct) {
                tmpObj[this.identificationDRProperty] = obj[this.identificationDRProperty];

                if (_.findWhere(this.recordData(), tmpObj)) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(this.positionProvider)) {
                this.setMaxPosition();
                obj[this.positionProvider] = this.maxPosition;
            }

            this.source.set(this.dataScope + '.' + this.index + '.' + this.recordData().length, obj);
        },

        /**
         * Check changed records
         *
         * @param {Array} data - array with records data
         * @returns {Array} Changed records
         */
        _checkGridData: function (data) {
            var cacheLength = this.cacheGridData.length,
                curData = data.length,
                max = cacheLength > curData ? this.cacheGridData : data,
                changes = [],
                obj = {};

            max.forEach(function (record, index) {
                obj[this.map[this.identificationDRProperty]] = record[this.map[this.identificationDRProperty]];

                if (!_.where(this.cacheGridData, obj).length) {
                    changes.push(data[index]);
                }
            }, this);

            return changes;
        }
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: Can you Please add the dynamic-rows-grid.js code in here. Because the error generated from there.

Comment: I added, but I didn't write that js file @RiteshSantra

Comment: @bugrag did you get any solution for this? i am getting the same issue.